Configure reload of a PowerBI report embedded in a React application
How can one configure reload of a PowerBI report embedded in a React application ?
Created React app by following this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5KFY5Jh1Uc
Question is similar to this.
https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react/issues/64
Currently reload happens (out-of-the-box) every 10 mins but would like to change to every second.
Report was created in PowerBI desktop with refresh set to 1 sec, and then published.
Tried solutions on this page but without success.
https://posts.flowpoint.ai/solved-how-to-refresh-powerbi-client-react-component-once-token-has-expired/
There must be a way to configure refresh/reload.
Any info is apprectiated.
